# Simple way for ajax calls in FLOW3?

Tags: ajax, json, typo3-flow

Actually I am working on a FLOW3 project and up to now it´s really great fun working with FLOW3, even if the documentation is not that good. But now I have problem: I want a JavaScript/jQuery function inside my frontend to call a controller action and the controller to return a json. As there is not much about this inside the documentation I tried a the way like in http://bytelude.de/2012/09/10/flow3-wie-erstelle-ich-eine-ajax-action-mit-json-ruckgabe/, but I always got a answer from the application that there is no view defined. I am using FLOW3 1.1.0. Maybe someone can give me a hint how to perform a ajax/json camm in a simple way.

Answer (score 0):

FLOW3 now uses Mime-Types instead of formats: The second example in the [Json View Section](http://flow3.typo3.org/documentation/guide/partiii/modelviewcontroller.html#json-view) should do the trick.
You have to set

```
protected $supportedMediaTypes = array('application/json', 'text/html');
```

instead of

```
protected $supportedFormats = array("html", "json");
```

now.

Comment: I changed it that way but I still got the message that no Template was found.

Comment: This is my entry in the routes.yaml`-
  name: 'Pages for TimeLine'
  uriPattern: 'Start/timeLineItemsAction'
  defaults:
    @package: 'My.Application'
    @controller: 'Start'
    @format: 'json'
    @action: 'timeLineItems'`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to check your Route.yaml, if you set the format to json, does it change something ?

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to bother with Json-Views and Mime-Types you can always just do this in your controller:

```
return json_encode($data);
```

When you return something (a string) in the Controller-Action, the view is never queried and the return gets used instead.